# is it possible to add an element to a list and preserve the order

Tags: python

I would like to add an element to a list that preserve the order of the list.

Let's assume the list of object is  *[a, b, c, d]* I have a function *cmp* that compares two elements of the list. if I add f object which is the bigger I would like it to be at the last position.

maybe it's better to sort the complete list...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bisect.insort` is a little bit faster, where applicable, than append-then-sort (unless you have a few elements to add before you need the list to be sorted again) -- measuring as usual on my laptop (a speedier machine will of course be faster across the board, but the ratio should remain roughly constant):

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import random, bisect; x=range(20)' 'y=list(x); bisect.insort(y, 22*random.random())'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.99 usec per loop
```

vs

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import random, bisect; x=range(20)' 'y=list(x); y.append(22*random.random()); y.sort()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.78 usec per loop
```

How much you care about this difference, of course, depend on how critical a bottleneck this operation is for your application -- there are of course situation where even this fraction of a microsecond makes all the difference, though they are the exception, not the rule.

The `bisect` module is not as flexible and configurable -- you can easily pass your own custom comparator to sort (although if you can possibly put it in the form of a key= argument you're *strongly* advised to do that; in Python 3, only key= remains, cmp= is gone, because the performance just couldn't be made good), while bisect rigidly uses built-in comparisons (so you'd have to wrap your objects into wrappers implementing `__cmp__` or `__le__` to your liking, which also has important performance implications).

In your shoes, I'd start with the append-then-sort approach, and switch to the less-handy bisect approach only if profiling showed that the performance hit was material. Remember [Knuth's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(computer_science)#When_to_optimize) (and Hoare's) famous quote, and [Kent Beck's](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast) almost-as-famous one too!-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is what [bisect.insort](http://effbot.org/librarybook/bisect.htm) is for, however it doesn't take a comparison function.  If the objects are custom objects, you can override one or more of the [rich comparison methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) to establish your desired sort order.  Or you could store a 2-tuple with the sort key as the first item, and sort that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
L.insert(index, object) -- insert object before index
```